# How to return timestamp based on user timezone?

Tags: php

Say that I have a timezone variable which is returned from a database that my users can set to their prefered time zone.  GMT+5 would return simply as:

```
$timezone = 5;
```

I need the users timezone so that I can reflect the date of an event in their particular time format.  Here is what I have so far:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p", strtotime($row["time"]));
}
echo $time;
```

How could I change the above output to reflect the time of the event based on the users preferred time zone?

```
//Output = 2017-01-15 12:09 AM 
//Expected Output: 2017-01-14 07:09 PM
```

Comment: You should definitely not use an integer to store the timezone. Use the timezone identifier, eg: `Europe/Paris`.

Comment: What if i'm going by GMT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` objects.

```
<?php

$storedDate = new DateTime('2017-01-15 12:09 AM');
$userDate   = (clone $storedDate)->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));

printf(
    "Stored Date:\t%s\nUser Date:\t%s\n",
    $storedDate->format(DATE_ATOM),
    $userDate->format(DATE_ATOM)
);

// outputs:
// Stored Date:    2017-01-15T00:09:00+00:00                                                                               
// User Date:      2017-01-15T01:09:00+01:00
```

As said in my comment, I dot not advise to store the timezone as an integer.

First, because some timezone can't fit an integer, for example India is up to 5:30 (`+0530`) from the UTC time.

Storing as integer also won't help you to properly handle summer time in some countries, or even in some region in a same country (see Brazil).

Timezone offset are subject to change, but defined configuration for a given location such as `Europe/Paris` are likely not.

Comment: Could you provide a solution for getting this to work under GMT (which is why I used the integers)

Comment: Using the `DateTimeZone` class you can any of the IANA Timezone (`Europe/Paris`) or UTC Offset such as `GMT+1` and such. However, again, storing timezone as integer is a bad idea, I'll edit my answer accordingly.